# How do I make a pointer hashable?

Tags: rust

In Rust, I want to treat enums as equal, but still be able to distinguish different instances by pointer. Here's a toy example:

```
use self::Piece::*;
use std::collections::HashMap;

#[derive(Eq, PartialEq)]
enum Piece {
    Rook,
    Knight,
}

fn main() {
    let mut positions: HashMap<&Piece, (u8, u8)> = HashMap::new();
    let left_rook = Rook;
    let right_rook = Rook;

    positions.insert(&left_rook, (0, 0));
    positions.insert(&right_rook, (0, 7));
}
```

However, the compiler wants me to define `Hash` on `Piece`:

```
error[E0277]: the trait bound `Piece: std::hash::Hash` is not satisfied
  --> src/main.rs:11:52
   |
11 |     let mut positions: HashMap<&Piece, (u8, u8)> = HashMap::new();
   |                                                    ^^^^^^^^^^^^ the trait `std::hash::Hash` is not implemented for `Piece`
   |
   = note: required because of the requirements on the impl of `std::hash::Hash` for `&Piece`
   = note: required by `<std::collections::HashMap<K, V>>::new`

error[E0599]: no method named `insert` found for type `std::collections::HashMap<&Piece, (u8, u8)>` in the current scope
  --> src/main.rs:15:15
   |
15 |     positions.insert(&left_rook, (0, 0));
   |               ^^^^^^
   |
   = note: the method `insert` exists but the following trait bounds were not satisfied:
           `&Piece : std::hash::Hash`

error[E0599]: no method named `insert` found for type `std::collections::HashMap<&Piece, (u8, u8)>` in the current scope
  --> src/main.rs:16:15
   |
16 |     positions.insert(&right_rook, (0, 7));
   |               ^^^^^^
   |
   = note: the method `insert` exists but the following trait bounds were not satisfied:
           `&Piece : std::hash::Hash`
```

I want equality defined on my enums so that one `Rook` is equal to another. However, I want to be able to distinguish different `Rook` instances in my `positions` hashmap.

How do I do this? I don't want to define `Hash` on `Piece`, but surely hashing is already defined on pointers?

Comment: Style note, you don't need the `: HashMap<&Piece, (u8, u8)>` type specification - it can all be inferred.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

There's a difference between *raw pointers* (`*const T`, `*mut T`) and *references* (`&T`, `&mut T`) in Rust. You have a reference.

`Hash` [is defined](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/blob/1.33.0/src/libcore/hash/mod.rs#L661-L673) for references as delegating to the hash of the referred-to item:

```
impl<T: ?Sized + Hash> Hash for &T {
    fn hash<H: Hasher>(&self, state: &mut H) {
        (**self).hash(state);
    }
}
```

However, it is [defined for raw pointers](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/blob/1.33.0/src/libcore/hash/mod.rs#L675-L707) as you desire:

```
impl<T: ?Sized> Hash for *const T {
    fn hash<H: Hasher>(&self, state: &mut H) {
        if mem::size_of::<Self>() == mem::size_of::<usize>() {
            // Thin pointer
            state.write_usize(*self as *const () as usize);
        } else {
            // Fat pointer
            let (a, b) = unsafe {
                *(self as *const Self as *const (usize, usize))
            };
            state.write_usize(a);
            state.write_usize(b);
        }
    }
}
```

And that works:

```
let mut positions = HashMap::new();
positions.insert(&left_rook as *const Piece, (0, 0));
positions.insert(&right_rook as *const Piece, (0, 7));
```

However, using either references or raw pointers here is iffy at best.

If you use a reference, the compiler will stop you from using the hashmap once you have moved the values you have inserted as the reference will no longer be valid.

If you use raw pointers, the compiler *won't* stop you, but then you will have dangling pointers which can lead to memory unsafety.

In your case, I think I'd try to restructure the code so that a piece is unique beyond the memory address. Perhaps just some incremented number:

```
positions.insert((left_rook, 0), (0, 0));
positions.insert((right_rook, 1), (0, 7));
```

If that seems impossible, you can always `Box` the piece to give it a stable memory address. This latter solution is more akin to languages like Java where everything is heap-allocated by default.

---

As [Francis Gagné says](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33847537/how-do-i-make-a-pointer-hashable/33847816#comment55460849_33847816):

> I'd rather wrap a `&'a T` in another struct that has the same identity semantics as `*const T` than have the lifetime erased

You can create a struct that handles *reference equality*:

```
#[derive(Debug)]
struct RefEquality<'a, T>(&'a T);

impl<'a, T> std::hash::Hash for RefEquality<'a, T> {
    fn hash<H>(&self, state: &mut H)
    where
        H: std::hash::Hasher,
    {
        (self.0 as *const T).hash(state)
    }
}

impl<'a, 'b, T> PartialEq<RefEquality<'b, T>> for RefEquality<'a, T> {
    fn eq(&self, other: &RefEquality<'b, T>) -> bool {
        self.0 as *const T == other.0 as *const T
    }
}

impl<'a, T> Eq for RefEquality<'a, T> {}
```

And then use that:

```
positions.insert(RefEquality(&left_rook), (0, 0));
positions.insert(RefEquality(&right_rook), (0, 7));
```

Comment: Raw pointers won't lead to memory unsafety if you never dereference them. However, that doesn't mean keeping raw pointers to deallocated objects is a good idea: another object could be allocated at the same memory location as a previously deallocated object. I'd rather wrap a `&'a T` in another struct that has the same identity semantics as `*const T` than have the lifetime erased.

Comment: Thanks! I settled on using Box for my project, but it's really useful having a comparison of the different approaches possible.

Comment: Raw pointers have the advantage that you don't need to add some kind of "ID" field. For example if you're processing a tree, then you might want to distinguish lots of `Node` instances that only differ in their tree position. Adding an ID to everything would suck.

Comment: @Timmmm in that example, you have the disadvantage that the programmer has to guarantee (outside of the compiler's knowledge) that the pointers will continue to be valid for as long as they are around. This can be very difficult to do in the presence of internal mutability.

Comment: True - I should have kept reading; the `RefEquality` solution is much better!

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the current answer, you can enhance the memory safety while using memory addresses as keys by introducing a wrapper over raw pointers that helps the Rust compiler to keep track of references.

You don't need to implement your own. [by_address](https://crates.io/crates/by_address) is a helpful crate that lets you do so. I would copy their demo as below:

```rust
use by_address::ByAddress;
use std::rc::Rc;

let rc = Rc::new(5);
let x = ByAddress(rc.clone());
let y = ByAddress(rc.clone());

// x and y are two pointers to the same address:
assert_eq!(x, y);

let z = ByAddress(Rc::new(5));

// *x and *z have the same value, but not the same address:
assert_ne!(x, z);
```