# Does lifetime elision work for methods in trait impls?

Tags: rust, lifetime

With this question I am looking for feedback from people who have more knowledge in this area. I am by no means an expert. So I might as well ask my question upfront: Is my reasoning correct here?

### The problem

Based on the [answer to a question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33847816/929981) here on SO, I was confused to see the lifetime elided in the implementation of a trait method:

```
impl<'a, 'b, T> PartialEq<RefEquality<'b, T>> for RefEquality<'a, T> {
    fn eq(&self, other: &RefEquality<T>) -> bool {
        self.0 as *const T == other.0 as *const T
    }
}
```

Here, in the method signature the lifetime `'b` was omitted on the type of `other`. This works and is correct. I expected it to be `&RefEquality<'b, T>` for the type to be correct. After all, the `'b` here is essential: The lifetime has to be different from `'a`. If not, it would be too restrictive: The implementation would only work for another `RefEquality<T>` with the same lifetime as `Self`. So those are obviously different semantics. How can the compiler infer the correct lifetime?

### Lifetime elision takes care of it

Lifetimes on function signatures can be elided but they cannot be elided on impl blocks. There, the types have to be fully specified which includes naming lifetimes.

On the `eq()` method on the other hand, I am able to elide the lifetime in the type annotation of other. In fact, the compiler then inserts an arbitrary lifetime for it which is obviously different from `'a`. That is the reason why this works while also keeping the same semantics:

```
impl<'a, 'b, T> PartialEq<RefEquality<'b, T>> for RefEquality<'a, T> {
    fn eq<'c>(&self, other: &RefEquality<'c, T>) -> bool {
        self.0 as *const T == other.0 as *const T
    }
}
```

Here, I introduced an arbitrary lifetime `'c` for the method, which is basically the same the compiler does in case of lifetime elision.

Naming a lifetime `'b` in my trait impl just stated that it has to be different from `'a` (I also not linked them in any way). It follows logically, that this does not work:

```
impl<'a, 'b, T> PartialEq<RefEquality<'b, T>> for RefEquality<'a, T> {
    fn eq(&self, other: &RefEquality<'a, T>) -> bool {
        self.0 as *const T == other.0 as *const T
    }
}
```

I said in on the impl the types would be different (based on their lifetimes) but now the actual `eq()` implementation says they are the same. This results in a type error as expected.

What if I want the lifetimes to be equal? Can I still use lifetime elision in this case, or will the compiler insert an arbitrary lifetime and report a type error?
It turns out, the inference works correctly here as well:

```
impl<'a, T> PartialEq<RefEquality<'a, T>> for RefEquality<'a, T> {
    fn eq(&self, other: &RefEquality<T>) -> bool {
        self.0 as *const T == other.0 as *const T
    }
}
```

The elided lifetime will be inferred to be `'a`, keeping the desired semantics that both `RefEquality<T>` types have to have the same lifetime.

Answer (score 7):

Let’s look at rustc’s process to determine if a provided `impl` method corresponds
to the signature declared in the trait.

The location in the code is
[`compare_impl_method`](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/blob/69b8e74c31c5bc2a35c40cecbceffba773cdecbf/src/librustc_typeck/check/compare_method.rs#L107-L171)
in `librustc_typeck/check/compare_method.rs`, and it's well commented,
however even the comments are hard to use for those that are not compiler hackers.

I’m not a compiler developer, so the following is based on my rust experience
and interpretation!

The declaration in the trait corresponds to a particular function type,
and the definition in the `impl` block is parsed to its own function type.

For this question I think only the conclusion of the type checking is important:

- “Is the `impl` function a subtype of the trait function?”

### Subtyping I

> [If S is a subtype of T](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subtyping), the subtyping relation is often written
>   S <: T, to mean that any term of type S can
>   be safely used in a context where a term of type T is expected.

It sounds reasonable. We want the `impl` block to define a function
that can be used safely as if it is the function declared in the trait.

### Case 1

This is the elided lifetime case, but spelled out explicitly.
I have replaced all method bodies with just a panic to emphasize that
function signature checking is completely uninfluenced by the
body of the function.

```
impl<'a, 'b, T> PartialEq<RefEquality<'b, T>> for RefEquality<'a, T> {
    fn eq<'c>(&self, other: &RefEquality<'c, T>) -> bool {
        panic!()
    }
}
```

The trait expects a function of type:

```
fn(&RefEquality<'a, T>, &RefEquality<'b, T>)
```

You provide a function of type:

```
fn<'c>(&RefEquality<'a, T>, &RefEquality<'c, T>)
```

It looks like the provided impl is “more general” than required.
With `'c ==  'b`, then the function is of equal type.

It is a subtype of the expected type, because we can always use the `fn<'c>` version
safely in its place.

### Case 2

For your second example, that didn't compile:

```
impl<'a, 'b, T> PartialEq<RefEquality<'b, T>> for RefEquality<'a, T> {
    fn eq(&self, other: &RefEquality<'a, T>) -> bool {
        panic!()
    }
}
```

You can add a bound `'b: 'a` ('b outlives 'a), and then [it's ok](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=d048b31502c96aa88a26&version=stable):

```
impl<'a, 'b: 'a, T> PartialEq<RefEquality<'b, T>> for RefEquality<'a, T> {
    fn eq(&self, other: &RefEquality<'a, T>) -> bool {
        panic!()
    }
}
```

The trait expects a function of type:

```
fn(&RefEquality<'a, T>, &RefEquality<'b, T>)
```

You provide a function of type:

```
fn(&RefEquality<'a, T>, &RefEquality<'a, T>)
```

I think it seems logical that they are compatible if 'b outlives 'a, but let's look at it calmly.

Let's remove the constant factors:

The trait expects a function of type:

```
fn(Ref<'b>)
```

You provide a function of type:

```
fn(Ref<'a>)
```

We also have the information that `where 'b: 'a`. How can we see that these are compatible?

### Subtyping II: Attack of the Variances

**Subtyping:** is it safe to use `X` instead of `Y`?

**Variance:** *if* `X` is a subtype of `Y`, what about `Foo<X>` and `Foo<Y>`?

See also [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Covariance_and_contravariance_(computer_science)), [Rustonomicon](https://doc.rust-lang.org/nightly/nomicon/subtyping.html) on variance.

The subtyping definition for lifetimes is:

`'x <: 'y` means that `'x` is longer than `'y`.

Let's practice subtyping and variance with references.

When is it safe to use `&'x i32` instead of `&'y i32`?

It is when `'x` is longer lived than `'y`, then it's
safe to replace. `'x` living longer than `'y` implies that
`&'x i32` is a subtype of `&'y i32`:

`'x <: 'y  => &'x i32 <: &'y i32`

The subtyping relation is propagated in the *same* direction,
and this is called **covariance**; `&'a i32` is **covariant** in the `'a` parameter.

The variance behavior of a function instead is this:

`X <: Y => fn(Y) <: fn(X)`

Functions behave in the opposite way of their argument types. This is **contravariance**,
logically “contra” since it's the *opposite* direction.

### Computation

For this question we assume that `Ref<'a>` behaves as
if it contains a `&'a` reference, and that it has the same *variance*
as `&'a` itself has.

We were given the bound `where 'b: 'a`, which means:

`'b <: 'a`

Use the covariance rule for references and Ref:

`'b <: 'a  =>  Ref<'b> <: Ref<'a>`

Use the **contravariant** rule for functions<sup>**</sup>

`Ref<'b> <: Ref<'a>  =>  fn(Ref<'a>) <: fn(Ref<'b>)`

And this was the question that rustc asked, is the `impl` function
a subtype of the trait function. It is!

** <sup>w.r.t. function arguments</sup>:

### What if I want the lifetimes to be equal?

If your goal is just to define `PartialEq` for the equal lifetime case, then yes, the elided lifetime case is fine. It provides a more general function in the impl, but the type checker determines that it is compatible.

You can also change the variance of your `RefEquality` type with respect to the lifetime parameter.

If you want a `RefEquality<'a, T>` is only subtype compatible
with exactly the same lifetime, that's called **invariance**.

There's a primitive you can use that has invariance, `std::cell::Cell<T>`.
`Cell<T>` is invariant in the `T` parameter.

The usual way to accomplish this is a `PhantomData` member:

```
struct RefEquality<'a, T: 'a> {
    ptr: &'a T,
    marker: PhantomData<Cell<&'a ()>>,
}
```

If you want to see an application of invariance, check out the
crossbeam crate and how [`Scope<'a>` being invariant in the `'a` 
parameter](https://github.com/aturon/crossbeam/blob/a6cebd0ead5042e1b22408a80940aa8a5f8d8d16/src/scoped.rs#L11-L13) is the cornerstone in its peculiar borrow rules for
safe scoped threads.

Comment: This... is an amazing answer. Kudos to all the work you obviously put into describing this!

Comment: Shouldn't it be `PhantomData<Cell<&'a T>>` rather than `PhantomData<Cell<&'a ()>>` in order to have correct dropping semantics with respect to the generic `T`?

Comment: `&T` has no dropck implications that I know, and there's already a `&T` in the type.

Comment: Ah right, I confused it with the example from the Rustonomicon.